# How can I make tabs scroll horizontally?

Tags: android

This code is not working. i don't know why though

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: You have only one tab, how you want to scroll it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) instead.

Comment: I need to use plane old tabs because I don't want anything to load off-screen